Removing an effect from a filter in Inkscape
In Inkscape's "Filter editor" dialogue, it is possible to add effects to a filter, but I have not found a way to remove an effect if I change my mind. How can I do this?

In versions below 1.3, right-click the effect in the list above and select 'Remove'.

Version 1.3 and after added a 'Remove effect' button on top of that.


Thank you! For some reason, right-clicking does not bring up the context menu when Inkscape is in full-screen mode. I'm running Inkscape 1.2.1 (9c6d41e, 2022-07-14) on macOS 12.3 if that helps.

Consider filing a bug report. I suspect it's not intentional that full-screen mode disables the R-click menu.

I ended up upgrading to 1.4 and looks like it has already been fixed.
